# How to use getUrl() in Magento to refer to another module?

Tags: magento, geturl

My module in Magento adminpanel has URL like as http://example.com/index.php/mymodule/... and contains custom grid with the orders. I want to redirect user to the standard "Order view" page when he clicks on a grid row.

```
public function getRowUrl($row)
{
    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
        return $this->getUrl('sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $row->getId()));
    }
    return false;
}
```

But this URL points to http://example.com/index.php/sales_order/view/... instead of http://example.com/index.php/**admin**/sales_order/view/... Any suggestion?

UPD. *config.xml*:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <mymodule>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Foo_Mymodule</module>
                <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
            </args>
        </mymodule>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Comment: Take a look at the correct config from [How to get the URL of a page/section in Magento admin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877683/how-to-get-the-url-of-a-page-section-in-magento-admin/6881211#6881211)

Comment: @clockworkgeek Thank you. Please look at my updated post. It looks similair to that case of config.xml, doesn't it?

Comment: Your `frontName` is `mymodule` but if you copy the example more closely it will be able to use `admin` instead.

Comment: My controller has a path `Foo/Mymodule/Adminhtml/MymoduleController.php`  I've tried to set `<adminhtml>
                <args><modules><mymodule after="Mage_Adminhtml">Foo_Mymodule_Adminhtml_Mymodule</mymodule>
                    </modules></args></adminhtml>` instead of current config, but attempt to access to module main page as `http://example.com/index.php/admin/mymodule/mymodule/index` appears 404 error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quite simply you need to replace `sales_order/view` with `*/sales_order/view`. The `*` means use the current router which in the admin is `adminhtml`.

**Edit**
To explain in more detail put this in your config,

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <mymodule after="Mage_Adminhtml">Foo_Mymodule_Adminhtml</mymodule>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Now the value `*/mymodule/index` will generate an URL `http://example.com/index.php/admin/mymodule/index` which in turn will load the file `Foo/Mymodule/controllers/Adminhtml/MymoduleController.php` and try to find the method `Foo_Mymodule_Adminhtml_MymoduleController::indexAction()`. If the method exists it is run, otherwise the admin router takes over and shows a 404 or redirects to the dashboard.

Comment: With `*/sales_order/view` it points to `http://example.com/index.php/mymodule/sales_order/view/`. I'm also surprised.

Comment: Thanks for your comment above, I've totally rewrote routing and paths in layout config, so everything works fine now with `*/sales_order/view`.

Comment: How did you rewrite things? I have exactly the same problem! using **/sales_order/view* also redirects me to *index.php/mymodule/sales_order/view/* instead of *index.php/admin/sales_order/view/*. Thanks for your help!