# Admin route in custom modules

Tags: php, magento, routes, adminhtml

All stock magento modules have URL path in backend which has 'admin' (by default) part.
However I was not able to achieve that for a custom module. Is this not possible or done on a purpose?

Thanks

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877683/how-to-get-the-url-of-a-page-section-in-magento-admin/6881211#6881211) for a best practice.

Comment: If I got you right, this [article](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_create_an_admin_form_module) will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of the URL is known as the "frontName".

```
http://example.magento.com/frontName/controllerName/actionName
```

Magento only allows a **single** module to claim a particular frontName.  For the `admin` frontname, that's `Adminhtml`.

**However**, Magento 1.3 introduced a configuration syntax that allows you to a tell particular module that's already claimed a front name that it (the module) should check **additional** modules for controller files.  This feature is often called [real controller overrides](http://web-magician.blogspot.com/2009/04/secret-feature-of-magento-13-sharing.html), and while you can use it to replace a particular controller in Magento with your own, you can **also** use (and **should** use it) it to setup your own controllers for the admin console.  The only caveat here is if Magento uses a controller name that you've already picked in a future version, you'll need to adjust things when you upgrade. (in other words, pick unique names)

If you're interested in the details, I'm in the middle of writing a series on Magento's [routing engine](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#dispatch), which will give you more detail than you'll ever need to know.