# Magento Module with Frontend and Admin functionality

Tags: magento, module, admin, frontend, controllers

I'm currently working on a custom module for Magento. I understand the basics of Packages, Modules and Routers, and I have built the front end part of my module.

However I am now moving on to the admin side of things. However I'm a little bit confused by how I add the admin part to my routers and get it to call the relevant controller.

Let's imagine I have created these routers...

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <slider>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Mypackage_Myodule</module>
                <frontName>Mymodule</frontName>
            </args>
        </slider>
    </routers> 
</frontend> 
<admin>
    <routers>
        <mymoduleadmin>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Mypackage_Myodule</module>
                <frontName>Mymodule</frontName>
            </args>
        </mymoduleadmin>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

I presume that both these routers will attempt to call controllers/IndexController.php and therefore the same functionality? Is it possible to set things up so my routers call different controllers depending on whether they are front end or admin? Is this even possible or do I need to set up a front end module and an admin module?

I apologise if this is a School Boy question, but this has me a bit confused and in reality I just want to know the most efficient way to set up a custom module with front end and admin functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending upon the area(frontend or adminhtml), frontend or adminhtml router are dispatched. 
So you need not need to worry about getting it messed up as long as you are using different controller files for frontend and adminhtml, frontend controller extending from `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action` & adminhtml extending from `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action`.

Frontend / Adminhtml routers can be defined as (just a syntax):

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <[module]>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>[Namespace]_[Module]</module>
                <frontName>[module]</frontName>
            </args>
        </[module]>
    </routers>
</frontend>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <[module]>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>[Namespace]_[Module]</module>
                <frontName>[module]</frontName>
            </args>
        </[module]>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

And you can create frontend controllers under: `app/code/[codePool]/[Namespace]/[Module]/controllers/`

For example:

```
<?php
//file: app/code/local/MagePsycho/Testmodule/controllers/IndexController.php
class MagePsycho_Testmodule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction(){

    }
}
```

In order to access it from url: `http://your-magento-url/testmodule/index/index`
and adminhtml controllers under:
`app/code/[codePool]/[Namespace]/[Module]/controllers/Adminhtml/`

For example:

```
<?php
//file: app/code/local/MagePsycho/Testmodule/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php
class MagePsycho_Testmodule_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction(){

    }
}
```

In order to access it from url: `http://your-magento-url/testmodule/adminhtml_index/index`
(You can see the Adminhtml folder for separating adminhtml controllers)

Hope this gave you some info.
Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry I thought I had this but I don't. What I suppose I'm lost by is what do I call my admin controller and where do I put it in the directory structure? As you say I need a standard index controller that extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action and an admin controller that extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action.

Comment: MagePsycho so my directory structure for my admin controller would look like /Module/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php..?

Comment: Yeah you are correct. Also, I have updated my post. Please check once.

Comment: @Robert Waller let me know if you have any queries?

Comment: I'm really sorry I've set this up as you say. But each router is just loading the front end controller. I can't get the admin router to load the /controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php it just loads /controllers/IndexController.php it seems I'm missing something really basic here. What http request would I make to access the admin controller? I assume it's just http://example.com/frontName..? If I give the front end and admin routes different front names?

Comment: How are you accessing your adminhtml controller actions?: You can use this pattern: http://your-magento-url/[frontName]/adminhtml_[controllerName]/[actionName]

Comment: Thanks a bundle that makes sense now. I was just missing a logic step in the routing.

Comment: Glad to could help you Robert:)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my similar question: [Admin route in custom modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521620/admin-route-in-custom-modules)

I also would recommend using

```
<admin>
 <routers>
   <adminhtml>
     <args>
       <modules>
         <modulename before="Mage_Adminhtml">Namespace_Module_Adminhtml</modulename>
       </modules>
     </args>
   </adminhtml>
 </routers>
</admin>
```

This will allow you to avoid using `adminhtml` part in the routes, so your module backend url will have simple and clean url like core modules e.g. `admin/mymodule`

Comment: Same here. I prefer this way to have cleaner url, though what MagePsycho say is also working.