# redirecting from admin page to a postAction on frontend

Tags: php, magento, redirect, magento-1.7

**Edited code:** now I'm not receiving the 404 Error but on the other hand there is nothing added on the database or on exception logs.

I need to call from my model php file a postAction function on a third part module ([VideoTestimonials from aheadWorks](http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/video-testimonials.html)) in order to reuse all their code to get the needed functionalities and avoid future bugs if I just copied the code and modified at will.

On a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217308/extending-overriding-extension-in-magento) I was pointed on the, I guess, right direction to accomplish this goal by using `setRedirect`. Here is the code I'm using on my php model file to try to redirect to the postAction on the frontend:

```
<?php
class Dts_Videotestimonials_Model_SearchVideo extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{

    function printVideoEntry($videoEntry, $_product, $tabs = "")
    {
        # get user data
        $user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
        $userName = $user->getUser()->getFirstname();
        $userEmail = $user->getUser()->getEmail();
        $data = array(
            "ProductId" => $_product->getId(),
                        "AuthorEmail" => $userEmail,
                        "AuthorName" => $userName,
                        "VideoLink" => $videoEntry->getVideoWatchPageUrl(),
                        "VideoType"  => "link",
                        "Title" => $videoEntry->getVideoTitle(),
                        "Comment" => "this is a comment"
        );
        $actionUrl = Mage::getUrl('vidtest/youtube/post', $data);
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($actionUrl);
    }
}
```

All the modifications to get here where ok, step by step (with help of @Francesco) I got to this point. But when I make this call I'm receiving a `404 Error`. What is wrong?

I was looking into this [SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792962/magento-module-with-frontend-and-admin-functionality) and [this post on the Magento forum](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/281412/#t398311) but can't make my self clear. The second one is a redirect from an event Observer, I do not know exactly if it can help.

Here is the full exception log on this error:

```
2012-09-04T14:25:17+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Zend_Controller_Response_Exception' with message 'Invalid HTTP response code' in C:\wamp\www\magento\lib\Zend\Controller\Response\Abstract.php:286
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\magento\lib\Zend\Controller\Response\Abstract.php(150): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setHttpResponseCode(Array)
#1 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Response\Http.php(106): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setRedirect('http://127.0.0....', Array)
#2 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\local\Dts\Videotestimonials\Model\SearchVideo.php(64): Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http->setRedirect('http://127.0.0....', Array)
#3 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\local\Dts\Videotestimonials\Model\SearchVideo.php(198): Dts_Videotestimonials_Model_SearchVideo->printVideoEntry(Object(Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry), Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
#4 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\local\Dts\Videotestimonials\Model\SearchVideo.php(244): Dts_Videotestimonials_Model_SearchVideo->printVideoFeed(Object(Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoFeed), Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 'Search results ...')
#5 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\local\Dts\Videotestimonials\controllers\Adminhtml\VideotestimonialsbackendController.php(28): Dts_Videotestimonials_Model_SearchVideo->searchAndPrint('s')
#6 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(419): Dts_Videotestimonials_Adminhtml_VideotestimonialsbackendController->postAction()
#7 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('post')
#8 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#9 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#10 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 C:\wamp\www\magento\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#12 {main}
```

Comment: It looks like you are redirecting to a page that doesn't exist. In this case, the url does not map to a controller such that the application can properly process your request. If you print out the contents of Mage::getBaseUrl().'vidtest/youtube/post', what is the full URL? If you navigate to that URL do you get a 404 (File Not Found) or some application error?

Comment: hmmm...tried an `echo` to see the $actionUrl and it is not correct: `http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/http:/index/127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/vidtest/youtube/`. Seems it's messing up with the `getbaseurl` and something else. And I get of course a `404 Error`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you using getUrl and getBaseUrl and it's the same thing, you can use this code:

```
$this->_redirect('module/controller/action','parameters');
```

but u have extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action on your class. its the best way. if isn't a controller so u shouldn't do this redirect.

Comment: Corrected the code and indeed I'm not receiving the 404 Error. But now I'm not getting anything at all, no inserts on the database or exception log. From model files I can do redirects using the `Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($actionUrl);`. Your sample is indeed to call from the controller action. Maybe I need to extend the controller action of the extension and call it from the module? This was suggested too as a possible solution on my previous question

Comment: +1 @Guerra I had not noticed that this code was in a model. Your data storage should be done in the model, and any redirects or application logic you need should be done in the controller.

Comment: @renab are right Yaroslav, you need extends controller to this class, and use one model to do db persistence. Its why magento is MVC.

Comment: Thanks both, will test tomorrow at first hour back at my desk ;)