# Magento redirect from adminthtml page to a frontend action

Tags: php, magento, redirect, observer-pattern, magento-1.7

Following [this post](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/dispatching-before-and-after-events-to-magento-core-actions/) I've finally managed to capture an event by extending the `Magento_Adminhtml_Controller_Action` and carry out some actions before it. But now I'm trying to improve it so I can capture another event triggered on the admin panel and from there pass an array through the `request` variable to another event on the frontend. I've these SO questions/answers, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265714/redirecting-from-admin-page-to-a-postaction-on-frontend) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749005/magento-redirect-customer-from-observer-method) but no way I can achieve what I need. I've tested the `observer code` using `die()` to be sure that the execution thread goes into the correct call and it is ok. I'm using the CommerceBug from AlanStorm, in case it can be used to get some light on this issue.

This is my Observer.php code.

```
<?php
class Dts_Videotestimonials_Model_Observer {

    public function hookToAdminhtmlControllerActionPreDispatch($observer)
    {
        if($observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName() == 'videotestimonials_adminhtml_videotestimonialsbackend_post')
        {
            // dispatching our own event before action upload video is run and sending parameters we need
            Mage::dispatchEvent("upload_video_before", array('request' => $observer->getControllerAction()->getRequest()));
        }
    }

    public function hookToUploadVideoBefore($observer)
    {
        //Hooking to our own event
        $request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest()->getParams();
        // do something with product

        $user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
        $userName = $user->getUser()->getFirstname();
        $userEmail = $user->getUser()->getEmail();

        $request['product_id'] = "16"; #$_product->getId(),
        $request['author_email'] = $userEmail;
        $request['author_name'] = $userName;
        $request['video_link'] = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y435u6kfExA&feature=youtube_gdata_player";
        $request['video_type']  = "link";
        $request['title'] = "AT&T Phone Nokia 2610";
        $request['comment'] = "this is a comment";
        Mage::dispatchEvent("vidtest_youtube_post", $request);
    }
}
```

**EDITED:**

Here is the full config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Dts_Videotestimonials>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Dts_Videotestimonials>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
          <videotestimonials>
            <class>Dts_Videotestimonials_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>videotestimonials_mysql4</resourceModel>
          </videotestimonials>
        </models>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch>
                <observers>
                    <controller_action_before>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>videotestimonials/observer</class>
                        <method>hookToAdminhtmlControllerActionPreDispatch</method>
                    </controller_action_before>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch>
            <upload_video_before>
                <observers>
                    <upload_video_before>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>videotestimonials/observer</class>
                        <method>hookToUploadVideoBefore</method>
                    </upload_video_before>
                </observers>
            </upload_video_before>
        </events>
        <helpers>
            <videotestimonials>
                <class>Dts_Videotestimonials_Helper</class>
            </videotestimonials>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
          <videotestimonials>
            <class>Dts_Videotestimonials_Block</class>
          </videotestimonials>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
          <videotestimonials>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
              <module>Dts_Videotestimonials</module>
              <frontName>videotestimonials</frontName>
            </args>
          </videotestimonials>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
          <videotestimonials module="videotestimonials">
            <title>Videotestimonials</title>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <children>
              <videotestimonialsbackend module="videotestimonials">
                <title>VideoTestimonials_Admin</title>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <action>videotestimonials/adminhtml_videotestimonialsbackend</action>
              </videotestimonialsbackend>
              <pending_video translate="title">
                  <title>Videos pendientes</title>
                  <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                  <action>videotestimonials/adminhtml_pendingvideos/pending</action>
              </pending_video>          
            </children>
          </videotestimonials>
        </menu>
        <acl>
          <resources>
            <all>
              <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
              <children>
                <videotestimonials translate="title" module="videotestimonials">
                  <title>Videotestimonials</title>
                  <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                  <children>
                    <videotestimonialsbackend translate="title">
                        <title>VideoTestimonials_Admin</title>
                    </videotestimonialsbackend>
                    <pending_video translate="title">
                      <title>Videos pendientes</title>
                      <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                    </pending_video>
                  </children>
                </videotestimonials>
              </children>
            </admin>
          </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
          <updates>
            <videotestimonials>
              <file>videotestimonials.xml</file>
            </videotestimonials>
          </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>            
            <videotestimonials_videotestimonialscron>
                <schedule><cron_expr>59 0 * */1 0</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>videotestimonials/cron::VideoTestimonialscron</model></run>
            </videotestimonials_videotestimonialscron>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

Comment: I Don't think this is an issue, but it could be:
$observer->getControllerAction() should be $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()

Comment: What problem, error occurs? if any?

Comment: @Andrew, I'm in the middle of another module development, also for Magento, as soon as I finish it I will comeback to this problem and then check your proposal, thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please post your config.xml code for the `events` tag?

Comment: @JMax edited and added full config.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what is happening. Your configuration of the admin controller is wrong. The proper way to include your controller in the admin section is this (you'll need to change out the module name, to match yours):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Video_Awesome>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Video_Awesome>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <Video_Awesome>
                <class>Video_Awesome_Model</class>
                <!-- No resource model used currently -->
            </Video_Awesome>
        </models>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch>
                <observers>
                    <controller_action_before>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Video_Awesome/Observer</class>
                        <method>controllerActionPredispatch</method>
                    </controller_action_before>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch>
            <upload_video_before>
                <observers>
                    <Video_Awesome>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Video_Awesome/Observer</class>
                        <method>uploadVideoBefore</method>
                    </Video_Awesome>
                </observers>
            </upload_video_before>
        </events>
    </global>

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
            <!-- we are not creating our own router, but tapping into the adminhtml router -->
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <!-- Your module name, and then
                        the path to the controller (minus
                        the controllers folder name). So,
                        in this instance, I put the router
                        in a "Adminhtml" folder inside of
                        the controllers folder, like thus:
        Video/Awesome/controllers/Adminhtml/videotestimonialsController.php -->
                        <Video_Awesome before="Mage_Adminhtml">Video_Awesome_Adminhtml</Video_Awesome>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

And, then, in your router (you don't need to call `getEvent` before getting the controller action):

```
public function controllerActionPredispatch ($observer)
{
    if($observer->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName() == 'adminhtml_videotestimonials_post') {
        // dispatching our own event before action upload video is run and sending parameters we need
    Mage::dispatchEvent("upload_video_before", array('request' => $observer->getControllerAction()->getRequest()));
    }
}
```

And finally, it doesn't sound as if you have a debugging setup for your Magento development.  I would highly recommend one. I use PHPStorm (I don't have any stake in the company - this is not an advertisement :), and it works awesome. Set a breakpoint there to see if what the variables are.

I would also recommend using `adminhtml_controller_action_predispatch_start`, instead of the global `controller_action_predispatch`, as it will only trigger in the backend (a very, very small performance difference).

Also, as a small sidenote, I saw in your `config.xml`, that you were specifying menu items/acl there. You probably didn't know, but that is deprecated functionality, and those items should be put it `adminhtml.xml`.

Comment: Just for the detailed answer you deserver a +1. I'm in the middle of another Magento related issue, I'll try to test your recommendations ASAP. PS: be alert, I will post some new question in a couple of min, maybe you could help