# How to make the condition in magento?

Tags: magento

Now, I want to output something when the user register my site, how to make the condition, namely:

```
If()
```

If the user  register my site, then on the  page echo something.eg:

When the user is not registered on my site, the page echo "test". If he is registered on my site, then echo "hello." But when he logged in my site the second time, the page should also echo "test".

How to make the condition. Thank you.

Comment: i didn't get you what you exactly says.. How we can know that the User is registered or not, when he browse the site with out he login in the site?

Comment: if the user register  my site and logged in my site the first time, on the onepage will echo "coupon code", if he logged in my site the second time. it will echo welcome.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()){
}
```

Comment: i have tried it,it can't get i want.  when the user  logged in my site the second time. i want to output something different of the first time the user  logged in my site

Comment: then you need to make a observer on customer_register_success

Comment: could you tell me how  to make a observer on customer_register_success  thank you

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding capturing the login event could be useful for what you want to achieve. See [this detailed tutorial](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/custom-magento-events-customer-first-order/) on how to do something very similar to what you are trying. On this case they are  offering a reward for first order a client has made.

I have struggling with a bigger task and one of my middle steps was to capture an event, wich I accomplished by following the previous posted link. It was very useful.

Here is one of [my questions about the subjetct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364478/magento-redirect-from-adminthtml-page-to-a-frontend-action) (capturing events and redirecting), maybe it can help you too.